# Implement balanced cruise control build from config over multiple VMs

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have recently undertaken a mammoth refactoring of 20 or so Cruise Control .config and Nant .build files. The intention was to consolidate all the VM build machines into a single one.

I have ended up with a single .config and .build file, with 20 satellite files for each application, containing data for each project. This seems to have worked fine. However, inevitably, performance has become an issue.

The most obvious thing to do is to split the cruise control .config file into chunks containing just the subset of projects to be built on that machine. However this seems a bit depressing, having gone to all the trouble of merging them.

I would like to be able to clone my build VM at will, and be able to "switch off" projects I do not want to build on that machine. Could this be done without having to rewrite the .config file each time I clone the build VM? Or even better, could this somehow be automated?

I am using Cruise Control 1.44 and Nant 0.85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You may be interested in setting the `initialState` to `Stopped` for each project then selectively start each project on the relevant server.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Configuration_Block

Are build labels relevant to you, if so you may want to consider centralising their generation somehow.

Comment: I didn't realise you could even start/stop projects on Cruise Control. I have a lot to learn. Is there a way to automate stopping/starting projects? Via the webservice?

Comment: I worked it out: the web request to start a project is `http://localhost/ccnet/server/local/project/$projectName/ViewProjectReport.aspx?StartBuild=Start`. I just used a powershell script to start Cruise Control, then instantiate `WebClient` and call its `OpenRead()` method to start each individual project.

Comment: CruiseControl will remember the state of the project at server start. So once the spread of projects has been configured you shouldn't need to run your powershell script

Comment: I believe `startupMode` is set to `UseLastState` by default.